# Operação I/O 'Block' loop?

Tags: python, loop, python-requests, try-catch, io

Saudações amigos, venho aqui pedir ajuda com relação a duvida sobre as operações de ***Request*** e com a operação ***Open***. Ate onde sei e li, a operação `file_request = requests.get(url_file,timeout=3,stream=True)` "Trava" a execução do código principal(Thread) ate que a requisição seja completada, não e mesmo? Mas na hora da escrita do arquivo, sendo ele seja muito grande, caso haja esse "block", a execução do loop também e parado, ou ele cria uma nova thread para cada operação I/O dentro do loop?

Minha duvida e por causa do tempo entre as requisições, para que não seja barrado pelo servidor acabei colocando um `time.sleep(3)`. Outra duvida, essa maneira de `try/catch` esta correta, ou seria melhor um *nested*? Tentei me expressar o máximo que consegui rsrs, por favor se não fui claro me de um toque para que eu corrija/ me expresse melhor. Obrigado a Todos!

```python
for post in thread.find_all("div", { "class" : "file" }):
  filetext_a = post.select_one('div.fileText a')
  saveFile(filetext_a)
  time.sleep(3)
```

```python
def saveFile(file_item):
  true_file_folder = download_folder + 'trueFiles/'
  url_file = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://',file_item['href'])
  try:  
    file_request = requests.get(url_file,timeout=3,stream=True)
    with open(true_file_folder + '%s' % file_item['href'].split('/')[4], 'wb') as f:
      for chunk in file_request.iter_content(chunk_size=128): 
            if chunk: 
                f.write(chunk) 
  except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)
  except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
  except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
  except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("OOps: Something Else",err)
  except IOError as err:
    print ("I/O Error:",err)
```